# The function $u\rightarrow \int_A|\nabla u|^2dx$ is continous

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let be $A$ an open set in $\mathbb{R^N}$ and $u\in C^1(A,\mathbb{R^N})$,

How can I show that the function $$u\rightarrow \int_A|\nabla u|^2dx $$

is continous?

Thanks

Comment: Continuous with respect to what metric on $C^1(A,\mathbb{R}^N$)?

Comment: @uniquesolution I consider the topology induced by the norm $||u||_1=||u||_0+||u'||_0$, where $||.||_0$ is the uniform norm

Comment: So if $u,v$ are close in your metric, then their gradients also have to be close , and uniformly on $A$. You must also assume something about the integrability of the gradients, but I suppose that's given too. Can you take it from here?

Comment: @uniquesolution yes thank you, it is something very direct....thanks!